# Limit to adding objects to a performSelector request (iOS4)

Tags: objective-c, ios4

If I use this code, the app works:

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(showUpdateRecordModalWithFrontWord:andBackWord:)]) {
        NSLog(@"seems to respond");
        [self.navigationController performSelector:@selector(showUpdateRecordModalWithFrontWord:andBackWord:) 
                withObject:[currentCard frontWord] withObject:[currentCard backWord]];


    }
```

If I add a third parameter (below), I get a SIGABRT.

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(showUpdateRecordModalWithFrontWord:andBackWord:andNotes:)]) {
        NSLog(@"seems to respond");
        [self.navigationController performSelector:@selector(showUpdateRecordModalWithFrontWord:andBackWord:andNotes:) 
                                        withObject:[currentCard frontWord] withObject:[currentCard backWord] withObject:[currentCard notes]];
    }
```

The method is here:

```
- (id)showUpdateRecordModalWithFrontWord:(NSString *)arg_name1 andBackWord:(NSString *)arg_name2 andNotes:(NSString *)arg_name3 {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    AppProductModalController *modal = [[AppProductModalController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [modal setNewRecord: NO];
    [modal setDelegate: self.topViewController];
    [modal.navBar.topItem setTitle: @"Update Card"];
    [modal.frontWordField setText: arg_name1];
    [modal.backWordField setText: arg_name2];
    [modal.notesField setText: arg_name3];
    [self presentModalViewController:modal animated:YES];
    [modal release];
    return nil;
}
```

Am I running into a limit of parameters, or am I just doing something wrong?

I appreciate any help..

Comment: Why are you sending `-performSelector…` instead of sending the message directly? For instance, `[self.navigationController showUpdateRecordModalWithFrontWord:[currentCard frontWord] andBackWord:[currentCard backWord]];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSObject only defines `performSelector:`, `performSelector:withObject:` and `performSelector:withObject:withObject:`. There's no magic behind the scenes here where you're "adding objects" — there just isn't such a method as `performSelector:withObject:withObject:withObject:`. Probably your best solution is to just send the message directly rather than going through `performSelector:`. The selector doesn't vary, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: " Probably your best solution is to just send the message directly"   Thanks! Would you mind showing me exactly how to do that?

Comment: @David DelMonte: As bavarious wrote in his comment, something like `[self.navigationController showUpdateRecordModalWithFrontWord:[currentCard frontWord] andBackWord:[currentCard backWord]]` should work. You might need to cast the navigation controller to keep from getting a warning, but that's a basic message send.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.. I didn't see Bavarious's message.. Note to self > learn to read.